# Google Static Maps custom icon url problem

Tags: google-maps-markers

Can Google Static Maps hold custom marker with https url? Have we same behavior with Google Maps API Premier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#URL_Parameters)

> Note that the Static Maps API does not support custom icon URLs that use HTTPS; the default icon will be displayed.